# JavaScript Regular Expression /shorthand/ vs Regexp(string)

Tags: javascript, regex

I have what I think are the same expressions one in the sorthand regex format, the other as a RegExp object with a string. I expect they would both be true but that's not what I'm seeing.

```
/^key$|^key([;,]\skey)+$/.test('key, key; key') //true

var rgxStr = '^key$|^key([;,]\skey)+$'; //
(new RegExp(rgxStr)).test('key, key; key'); //false
```

What is going on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As soon as you're defining regexp in a string - you have to escape backslashes

```
var rgxStr = '^key$|^key([;,]\\skey)+$';
```

Comment: Ha, that's it. It's the double edged sword of coding late at night.

Answer (score 3):

Look here:

```
var rgxStr = '^key$|^key([;,]\skey)+$';
//                           ^ whoa, a backslash!
```

In a regular expression literal, JavaScript interprets that backslash as part of the regular expression.
In a normal string literal, JavaScript doesn't know what to do with `\s` and discards the backslash.

To fix it, escape your backslash in the string literal:

```
var rgxStr = '^key$|^key([;,]\\skey)+$';
```